# SQL Server : DateTime Stored as Int With Weird Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I am querying a database that is maintained by another company, and I am pulling dates from their database, but they are stored as integers. They have 9 digit values, such as:

- 577976126
- 595678891

etc.

These dates are apparently all within the past few days when I query for the same record using their front-end application, however, I cannot determine what format of dates they are using. Trying to cast or convert these values into datetimes or the like all throw errors.

Is the 9-digit date format starting with 5 a SQL Server thing? Or is it a convention set by this third party company? If anyone has any information, even as to what the date format could be and how to convert, that would be extremely helpful.

EDIT:

Here are some examples comparing the SQL value and the front-end datetime.

```
595678891 - 11/14/18 9:05  
595672666 - 11/13/18 20:35  
581623591 - 06/06/18 18:06
```

All front-end times are in EST, I believe.

Comment: int is not a datetime. They have their own convention on how to store datetime, which is always a  bad idea. You will have to ask them how to convert this, but better would be to tell them to send you datetimes, not integers

Comment: It would certainly help if you could give the actual corresponding dates (and possibly times) as shown in the Frontend.

Comment: `Is the 9-digit date format starting with 5 a SQL Server thing` : No. `is it a convention set by this third party company?` Yes, some people like to reinvent the wheel. `If anyone has any information, even as to what the date format could be and how to convert, that would be extremely helpful.` <= Unlikely. You will need to contact this 3rd party and ask them or update the question with exactly which 3rd party this is and *maybe* an so member had previous experience with them and knows what these values mean.

Comment: I think this question should be closed until the "other company" has been asked about it. If they can or will not answer it could be reopened but with some example data from both database and from-end.

Answer (score 5):

Just a guess, but they look like seconds from **2000-01-01**

**Example**

```
Select dateadd(second,595678891,'2000-01-01')
```

**Returns**

```
2018-11-16 10:21:31.000
```

Comment: I was about to write this answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I suspect you've seen these values before  :)

Comment: This was my original thought, or that it was some kind of offset, and it gets the numbers in the ballpark, but not exactly.

Comment: @JakeConniff Then we would need to know the other side of the equation to determine the proper approach

Comment: @JakeConniff Perhaps UTC.  What timezone are you in?

Comment: There could also very well be a time zone difference if this is within 24 hours of what you're expecting......ninja'ed by mere seconds.

Comment: Local time zone for me and the database is EST.

Comment: @JakeConniff Your last example returns 1999-12-31 23:59:29   Select dateadd(SECOND,-581623591,'2018-06-06 18:06')

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's being stored as an [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) which is an integer since it's a representation of the time elapsed since a chosen start date.

You have to know what the starting date is in order to convert properly.  For example, the most common epoch is the Unix epoch which starts on Jan 1, 1970.  All dates are calculated as time elapsed since that date.

You might be able to use online [epoch calculators](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to figure out the epoch date being used. I tried with your samples and found that Jan 1, 2000 for the first item returns Nov 16, 2018 which seems to fit your expectations.

You need to find out what epoch is being used to be sure...